# Is there a way to add a custom log4j appender in the configuration?

Tags: java, log4j, playframework

I'm writing a custom log4j appender, and it seems Play! can't find it if I put it in the log4j.properties because of classpath issues.

I found [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/log4play-log4j-appender-and-ui) that suggests adding it programatically.
Is there a cleaner solution that still allows it to be configured in the standard way?

Comment: What classpath issue? Is your appender implementation actually in the classpath?

Comment: @fge - yes, but when Play reads log4j.properties, it has not loaded the application yet. My logger is currently inside the app. Is the correct thing to do to wrap it as a Play Module, and load it via dependencies.yml?